# Why my own authentication doesn't work with my own model in Laravel?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4.2 and I'm trying to auth my own model (I don't use `User` model).
The problem appears when pass the mail and password, then I use the method `Auth::attempt` and **enters to else (that it corresponds to the error)**

**Usuario Controller**

```
class UsuarioController extends BaseController{

function doLogin(){
    $userdata = array(
        'Correo' => Input::get('correo'),
        'Contrasena' => Input::get('contrasena')
        );
    if(Auth::attempt($userdata)){
        echo 'SUCCESS!';

    }else{
        echo 'Error!';

    }
} ...
```

**Usuario Model**

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
class Usuario extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
protected $table = 'Usuario';
protected $primaryKey = 'idUsuario';
protected $fillable = array(
                        'Nombre',
                        'Apellido',
                        'Rol',
                        'Correo',
                        'Contarsena',
                        'Cumpleanos',
                        'Foto', 
                        'Pais',
                        'Comuna',
                        'Profesion_idProfesion',
                        'Institucion_idInstitucion',
                        'remember_token'
                    );

function profesion(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Profesion', 'idProfesion');
}


public function getPasswordAttribute()
{
    return $this->Contrasena;
}

public function setPasswordAttribute($Contrasena)
{
    $this->Contrasena= $Contrasena;
}   

public function getReminderEmail()
{
    return $this->Correo;
}    

public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->remember_token;
}

public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    $this->remember_token = $value;
}

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'remember_token';
}
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}
public function getAuthPassword() {
    return $this->Contrasena;
}       

}
```

**Auth.php**

```
return array(

'driver' => 'eloquent', //database or eloquent

'model' => 'Usuario',

'table' => 'Usuario',

'username' => 'Correo',
'password' => 'Contrasena',

'reminder' => array(

    'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',

    'table' => 'password_reminders',

    'expire' => 60,

),

);
```

**Usuario Table**

[image]

The application never crash but in the **If Condition** always enter to the ''else'' returns **Error!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your fillable array:

```
protected $fillable = array(
                    'Nombre',
                    'Apellido',
                    'Rol',
                    'Correo',
                    'Contarsena',
                    'Cumpleanos',
                    'Foto', 
                    'Pais',
                    'Comuna',
                    'Profesion_idProfesion',
                    'Institucion_idInstitucion',
                    'remember_token'
                );
```

**Contarsena** should be **Contrasena**

And your auth array should contain a `email` and `password` key:

```
$userdata = array(
    'correo' => Input::get('correo'),
    'password' => Input::get('contrasena')
);
```

Comment: if I do that returns ``Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `Usuario` where `email` = marcelo@example.com limit 1)`` so I replace ``email`` by ``Correo`` and works :D

Answer (score 0):

try

```
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

to get the the SQL executed. That makes troubleshooting easier.

My guess is that there's no 'password' field, which the attempt method will automatically hash